# 405 error with JIRA REST API using node js

Tags: jira-rest-api

I am trying to create an automated JIRA ticket using the REST API but I keep getting a 405 error.

I am using the examples here: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/

Also, when I visit the post URL directly I do not get any errors so I doubt it is a server issue. Any ideas?

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
client = new Client();
// Provide user credentials, which will be used to log in to Jira.
var loginArgs = {
    data: {
        "username": "user",
        "password": "pass"
    },
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
};
client.post("https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/auth/1/session", loginArgs, function(data, response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        //console.log('succesfully logged in, session:', data.session);
        var session = data.session;
        // Get the session information and store it in a cookie in the header
        var args = {
            headers: {
                // Set the cookie from the session information
                cookie: session.name + '=' + session.value,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            data: {
                // I copied this from the tutorial
                "fields": {
                    "project": {
                        "key": "REQ"
                    },
                    "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
                    "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
                    "issuetype": {
                        "name": "Request"
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        // Make the request return the search results, passing the header information including the cookie.
        client.post("https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta", args, function(searchResult, response) {
            console.log('status code:', response.statusCode);
            console.log('search result:', searchResult);
        });
    } else {
        throw "Login failed :(";
    }
});
```

I am expecting the Jira ticket of type REQ to be created with the details I added in the fields section.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the incorrect REST API; what you're currently doing is doing a POST to [Get create issue meta](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/issue-getCreateIssueMeta) which requires a GET method, hence, you're getting a 405. If you want to create an issue, kindly use [Create issue](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/issue-createIssue) (`POST /rest/api/2/issue`) instead.